# What is the best way to ftp upload multiple files in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I'm a not expereienced programmer en VB.

I'm creating a desktop application where the user uploads some files to a server via ftp.

The files are all in the same folder in local and uploads to the same folder at the server.

By the momment i'm working with this code:

```
For Each File As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles( _
                                    path, _
                                    FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, _
                                    "*.jpg")
    Dim fileInf As IO.FileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(File)
    Dim uri As String = serveruri
    Dim reqFTP As Net.FtpWebRequest
    reqFTP = Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(uri))   
    reqFTP.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(user, pass)
    reqFTP.KeepAlive = False
    reqFTP.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile    
    reqFTP.UseBinary = True
    reqFTP.ContentLength = fileInf.Length
    Dim buffLength As Integer = 2048
    Dim buff(buffLength) As Byte
    Dim contentLen As Integer  
    Dim fs As IO.FileStream = fileInf.OpenRead()
    Dim strm As IO.Stream = reqFTP.GetRequestStream()
    contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)
    While Not (contentLen = 0) 
        strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen)
        contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)
    End While 
    strm.Close()
    fs.Close()        
Next
```

With this code i upload one by one the files but the total spent time is too big.

How can i reduce the total spend time?

I have thought to do it with threads or upload the files asynchonously but i couldn't find any example of how to do it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we use this code to do a similar job asynchronously:

```
  w = New System.Net.WebClient

        w.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(username, Password)

        w.UploadFileAsync(New System.Uri("ftp://ftp.yourdomain/yourfilename"), bupath)
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for our ansker. I'm working with that and now i have better results. I have set a empty proxy credentials with `w.prowx = new WebProxy()` and i have set the maximum number of connexions to 30 with `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 30` I'm still working on it!

Answer (score 0):

User my FTP class

```
Public Class FTP
        '-------------------------[BroCode]--------------------------
        '----------------------------FTP-----------------------------
        Private _credentials As System.Net.NetworkCredential
        Sub New(ByVal _FTPUser As String, ByVal _FTPPass As String)
            setCredentials(_FTPUser, _FTPPass)
        End Sub
        Public Sub UploadFile(ByVal _FileName As String, ByVal _UploadPath As String)
            Dim _FileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName)
            Dim _FtpWebRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(_UploadPath)), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
            _FtpWebRequest.Credentials = _credentials
            _FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive = False
            _FtpWebRequest.Timeout = 20000
            _FtpWebRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
            _FtpWebRequest.UseBinary = True
            _FtpWebRequest.ContentLength = _FileInfo.Length
            Dim buffLength As Integer = 2048
            Dim buff(buffLength - 1) As Byte
            Dim _FileStream As System.IO.FileStream = _FileInfo.OpenRead()
            Try
                Dim _Stream As System.IO.Stream = _FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
                Dim contentLen As Integer = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)
                Do While contentLen <> 0
                    _Stream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen)
                    contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength)
                Loop
                _Stream.Close()
                _Stream.Dispose()
                _FileStream.Close()
                _FileStream.Dispose()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Upload Error: ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End Sub
        Public Sub DownloadFile(ByVal _FileName As String, ByVal _ftpDownloadPath As String)
            Try
                Dim _request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(_ftpDownloadPath)
                _request.KeepAlive = False
                _request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
                _request.Credentials = _credentials
                Dim _response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = _request.GetResponse()
                Dim responseStream As System.IO.Stream = _response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim fs As New System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
                responseStream.CopyTo(fs)
                responseStream.Close()
                _response.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Download Error: ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End Sub
        Public Function GetDirectory(ByVal _ftpPath As String) As List(Of String)
            Dim ret As New List(Of String)
            Try
                Dim _request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(_ftpPath)
                _request.KeepAlive = False
                _request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails
                _request.Credentials = _credentials
                Dim _response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = _request.GetResponse()
                Dim responseStream As System.IO.Stream = _response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim _reader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream)
                Dim FileData As String = _reader.ReadToEnd
                Dim Lines() As String = FileData.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                For Each l As String In Lines
                    ret.Add(l)
                Next
                _reader.Close()
                _response.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Directory Fetch Error: ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
            Return ret
        End Function

        Private Sub setCredentials(ByVal _FTPUser As String, ByVal _FTPPass As String)
            _credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(_FTPUser, _FTPPass)
        End Sub
    End Class
```